# When to use Properties.Settings.Default in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, configuration, settings

What are the best practices for using the Properties.Settings.Default config settings in C#? I see it commonly, but I often don't know when to utilize it vs. when I should just hard code values. Thanks!

Comment: MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397759.aspx

Comment: That type of properties are for things that the end-user can potentially change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I try to avoid hardcoding values in code, mainly because if there's ever a need to change their value it requires a re-compile of the app.

It's usually beneficial to have some sort of common object that exposes all your settings via public properties so that you are referencing the settings the same way throughout the app.

Example:

```
public static SomeReferenceClass
{
     public static string TimeOfDay { get{ return Properties.Settings.Default.TimeOfDay; }}
}
```

Then Later on to call it

```
SomeReferenceClass.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: My main concern is having huge lines of text like `Properties.Settings.Default.TimeOfDay` in my code when I could simply have a variable named `timeOfDay`.

Comment: @grantmc not sure if it helps any more but added a bit more to my answer. Doing it that route also means if your property name in the config file changes it only needs to be updated once in your code, since everything else would reference that property.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb has always been that if the values of the properties need to change without modifying the code then make them an external/configurable property.  If you will never need to change their value, then they're a constant and can be hard-coded.

Basically, if these values need to be configured/changed put them in `Properties.Settings.Default`.  You can hard code constants.

Answer (score 0):

personally, I use the default setting when the user or application setting are not specified or persisted.

I'd never hardcode a setting that might change based on any number of variables such as environment, user, application, or whatever.

I generally create settings providers that implement an interface.  That way, you can easily change out how to gather your configuration settings without changing the business logic.